# NSClassFromString() in ARC semantic issue "No known instance method for selector 'xxx:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

the Code:  `[NSClassFromString(@"Test") gotoTest];`

- usage ARC with Error: `No known class method for selector 'gotoTest'`
- but in MRC warning no error.

Way ARC from warning becomes an error ? do you have any reference? I want to know the essential reason.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the warning under MRC:

> Class method '+gotoTest' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

and this contains a vital clue – the compiler is looking for the *return type*. Under MRC it assumes `id` and will let you assign the result as an object reference. If you mess up and the return type is, say, `float`, things will probably go wrong.

Under ARC it is the compilers job to do the memory management of any returned value, and to do this correctly it needs to the the type. So if it can't determine the return type it produce an error.

Your code fragment suggests you know the selector takes no arguments and returns no value, so declare it as such. If you've no class with the method you can use a protocol, something like:

```
@protocol GotoTest
   + (void) gotoTest;
@end
```

will do. Now the compiler knows the types and your code will compile under ARC.

HTH